# Increase password prompt timeout for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7

We are usually using ssh + keys to access our servers.

Recently I had to give a password to another person to enter into the login prompt in person at the client location, with monitor and keyboard and all. I wanted secure servers so I set all passwords to 50 random characters. Never actually tested that a normal person can enter them.

The problem is that shortly after you start entering the characters the password prompt resets. I'ts not that shortly, but its 50 characters...

Can I somehow get that timeout increased?

PS. I'm talking about this screen: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible to set in `/etc/login.defs` with the value `LOGIN_TIMEOUT`.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html

```
       LOGIN_TIMEOUT (number)
           Max time in seconds for login.
```

Comment: This was what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Good to know it worked. :)

Answer (score -1):

Change Login Grace Time .  set 1 minutes or 5 mins as per your requirements

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
LoginGraceTime 1m
```

if wants to disable login session during ssh login set

```
LoginGraceTime 0
```

for more info - https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config

Comment: This is not about ssh. I'ts about the default login screen. Imagine you just installed a server and you have a keyboard and mouse and have to type in username and password.

Comment: you will type username and password in terminal. right ? grace time allow you more time to type username and password.

Comment: Yes. Default terminal. Not ssh, not sudo prompt. Just a new installation and  the screen that opens up. https://i.imgur.com/0Mpot50.png  How do I change that grace 
 time?

Comment: do you want increased time during installation ? if you have multiple servers, you can write ansible/chef to change in config.

Comment: Just tell me how to do it after installation. I can do the rest.

Comment: after installation you can write ansible playbook to change config . or create custom  image with updated configs and create new servers using that image